# jquery output text in htmlentities except line break

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.click').click(function(){
    var t = 'hello /n world';
    $('.target').text(t);
});
```

I have a button, it replace string after click.

if I use `text()` it will convert all string into `htmlentites` and I can't keep line break

if I use `html()` I will get xss attack)

(var t should be text data fetch out from database)

any suggestion?

Comment: what is mean by xss attack.?

Comment: if string is t='<script>...'; and I use html(t); output, it will out the script

Comment: What's the element you're placing the text in? You could use a textarea or a pre tag to respect newlines. Failing that, split the string on newlines and place each "line" in a block element. Failing that, use one of the many newline-to-br snippets.

Comment: var t should be text data fetch out from database, therefor i must prevent xss

Comment: ok so why dot you remove all script tags from t ?

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
var t = 'hello /n world';
t = t.replace(/\/n/g, "\n")
$('.word')[0].innerText = t;
```

as \n should be used for new line character.